# Android - Shared element transitions with calling activity finish()

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-finish, shared-element-transition

I'm working on making an application more Material and I'm just stuck on how to implement some shared element transitions. I have an activity A that starts another B and then calls finish() in order to remove it from the back stack. In my case I have an element I want to share between the two activities, but once it is passed from A to B, A no longer matters.
If I don't call finish() after startActivity(ctx,intent, bundle) the exit/enter animation works perfectly. However, if I do call finish, there's a really ugly flicker before the animation starts.

Is there something I'm overlooking or is it just not possible to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can finish your activity in the onStop function, if you only want this to happen when you transition from A to B then create a flag and set it after you call startActivity(ctx,intent, bundle):

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mShouldFinish)
         finish();
}
```

Make sure when you are done with activity B to call finish() and not finishAfterTranstion() since activity A is no longer there

After finishing the activity A, shared element in B might hang in screen if you press back. Set transitionName to null in `ActivityB.onEnterAnimationComplete` to avoid this.

Comment: This does not work for me, the shared element transition is not correct when I do this. Everything is fine if I don't finish Activity A but I want to do so after the transition is finished. Can't get this to work.

Comment: Only this solution worked when using shared elements transition

Comment: It almost was great solution for me... but it doesn't work on huawei :)

Answer (score 31):

*UPDATE*

Much better and simpler way

```
ActivityCompat. finishAfterTransition(this);
```

<3 support library.

Comment: I cant seem to find `finishWithTransition`. So I tried `finishAfterTransition` and did not work either.

Comment: Its in support library. Also try bumping your targetSDK version

Comment: The call is actually:

ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);

Just tested and it works great.

Comment: this still causes flickering for me using a shared element.

Comment: what do you mean by flickering ? can you upload some gif some where and post link here

Comment: @ksarmalkar, `finishAfterTransition` doesn't call `finish` *after* the transition is complete; it just calls `finish` immediately. So if you are transitioning from Activity A to B, and B fades in, then A is gone so the Home screen bleeds through (or possibly another Activity). Note: this seems to happen only when using shared transitions.

Comment: `finishAfterTransition` is just calls after the activity transition, the shared elements is a different transition and you need to do the ```boolean```trick.

Comment: `ActivityCompat. finishAfterTransition(this);` is buggy, sometimes it is finishing, sometimes not, sometimes it is even causing crashes......

Answer (score 7):

This is maybe late but I had the same issue.
What worked for me is:

```
supportFinishAfterTransition();
```

This is included in the support library and works like charm.

PS: you don't needto call `finish()` when you call `supportFinishAfterTransition()` .

Answer (score 4):

I've written a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663116/1635817) which I find a bit more elegant as you don't need a field.
This is still far from ideal but it works in my use case which is basically a splash screen with a transition to the next screen and I want the splash screen to be closed right away.
This works because `onStop` is called when the activity is not visible anymore, thus at that point we can actually close it without causing artifacts (in this case this blinking / flickering)

```
lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleEventObserver {
    override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
            finish()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out **finishAfterTransition()** method in 5.0 and above you can finish the activity after the exit transition occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, android.view.View, String)` to make your transition you should use its callback method in Activity B to finish Activity A.

```
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedElementEnd(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
            super.onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots);
                // finish Activity A

        }
    });
```