# Previous activity finishes without completing exit transition

Tags: android

I have a splash screen activity which is supposed to launch a landing activity and finish itself. When I enable activity transitions, with a simple slide animation as both enter and exit animations, I see that the splash activity finishes before the landing activity slides up completely. This causes an intermediate phase when users see the Android launcher screen.

I tried using `finishAfterTransition()` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547439/android-shared-element-transitions-with-calling-activity-finish/45028546), but no luck. Is this a bug in the support library? Or am I not supposed to use transitions on activities which may finish after launching a new activity?

Answer (score 0):

The method `overridePendingTransition()` and animation parameters `R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.fade_out` have worked for some.

It is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320875/8560690)

Comment: This approach is bypassing the transition api wand thus will not let me use any methods like explode, etc.