# Background screen appearing for a fraction of second when using android shared element transition animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am trying to build my first android application where I have two activities (first one is the splash screen and second one is login screen) and I am using shared element transition when moving from first activity to the second one. But I am doing something wrong because of which the transition is not smooth and for a split second of time, the background screen is appearing between the two activities. Refer to the GIF for better understanding

[image: GIF]

I was able to capture the frame that was appearing between the activities. It looks like following,

[image]

You can see the `ImageView` of first activity is still visible in the frame. Even the `textView` containing "Hello, Welcome back" is also visible.

I am sharing the activity layout and corresponding java files below,

**activity_main.xml (splash screen)**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#1f1f1d"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashLogo"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        android:transitionName="logo_anim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_login.xml (login screen)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1f1f1d"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:transitionName="logo_anim"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Hello,\nWelcome Back"
        android:textColor="#BFAD0F"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
        android:text="Login to continue"
        android:textColor="#CCC588"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        // This part has the login form and buttons,
        // not adding them here as they seems to be 
        // unnecessary in this context
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**main_activity.java (splash)**

```
private static int SPLASH_TIMEOUT = 3000;

Animation splashAnimation;
View splashView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    splashAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.splash_animation);
    splashView = findViewById(R.id.splashLogo);
    splashView.setAnimation(splashAnimation);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, splashView, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(splashView));
            startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());

            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIMEOUT);
}
```

**login.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#1f1f1d"));
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

I have tried solution stated in lot of different stackoverflow questions about blinking/flashing shared element transition, nothing worked. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `windowBackground` for your app's theme? Maybe it is transparent and there is a split second before the `#1f1f1d` background of the activity is inflated.

Comment: `windowBackground` in app's theme was not set initially, but setting it the same color `#1f1f1d` didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the activity you're trying to call is not ready when you're calling finish()

You can solve it by adding the finish in onStop method

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   finish(); 
}
```

you can find more detail on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663116

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. Thanks